Release build (R8 enabled) Typesafe Navigation, Kotlinx Serialization and Inner class - Decompiled Class: INSTANCE MISSING
I am building an app using type safe navigation.
Destinations
    @Serializable
    data object OwnerGraph {
    
        @Serializable
        data object HistoryGraph {
    
            @Serializable
            data object HistoryScreen
        }
}

The Navigation graph:
fun NavGraphBuilder.historyScreenOwnerNavGraph() {
    navigation<OwnerGraph.HistoryGraph>(
        startDestination = OwnerGraph.HistoryGraph.HistoryScreen
    ) {
        composable<OwnerGraph.HistoryGraph.HistoryScreen> { navBackStackEntry ->
            val navHostController = LocalNavHostContoller.current
            Text("History Screen")
        }
    }
}

The Navhost
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = startingNavigationGraph,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(paddingValues)
        .consumeWindowInsets(paddingValues)
) {
    historyScreenOwnerNavGraph()

}

And when I run the app I get this error:
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'OwnerGraph$HistoryGraph' is not found.
                                                                                                    Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied.

But I applied the plugin and added the corresponding library.
And what is wierd is this is just a cut out of my whole codebase.
I use this structuring elswhere as well and there is not a crash like this.
But all of a sudden it has problem with this particularly one.
I would like to imagine this structure for the Type safe graph of mine which makes it more understandable.
Note: The crash only happens when I run the app with R8 enabled and in release build
Update: I am decompiling the classes and I found that the declaredFields is empty and INSTANCE is missing : No such static field 'INSTANCE'
While other cases the INSTANCE is there and I did the same thing

Missing fields:

Update: If I add the @Keep annotation it start working again

Make sure you imported from @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable and properly setup plugin in build.gradle,
Module:
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.7.10" apply false
App:
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization")
Then try the start destination as, startDestination = OwnerGraph.HistoryGraph

It works for every other data object. I found for some reason hen I enable R8 the INSTANCE is not kept for some reason
